# How to mock objects in Erlang using Meck?

Tags: erlang, mocking, tdd, stub, meck

Okay, I'm using Meck and I'm lost.  My first language (that I've been writing for about 7 months) is Ruby, so I can't seem to wrap my brain around Meck mocking yet.  I do get Ruby mocking though.  Hoping someone can help me.  Also, I've only been writing Erlang for a week.

**Updated Code (but mocking still isn't working)...**

I have a Erlang <strike>console_io</strike> prompter module that looks like this:

```
    -module(prompter).
    -export([prompt/1, guess/0]).

    prompt(Message) ->
      console_io:gets(Message).

    gets() ->
      {_, [Input]} = io:fread("Enter:  ", "~s"),
      Input.

    guess() ->
      Guess_Input = gets(),
      Guess_List = convert_guess_to_list(Guess_Input).

    convert_guess_to_list(Guess_Input) ->
      re:split(Guess_Input, "", [{return, list}, trim]).
```

My test now looks like this:

```
    -module(prompter_test).
    -include_lib("eunit/include/eunit.hrl").

    guess_1_test() ->
      meck:new(prompter),
      meck:expect(prompter, gets, fun() -> "aaaa" end),
      ?assertEqual(prompter:guess(), ["a","a","a","a"]),
      ?assert(meck:validate(prompter)),
      meck:unload(prompter).
```

The error I'm getting is this:

```
    Eshell V5.9.3.1  (abort with ^G)
    1> prompter_test: guess_1_test (module 'prompter_test')...*failed*
    in function prompter:guess/0
      called as guess()
    in call from prompter_test:guess_1_test/0 (test/prompter_test.erl, line 10)
    in call from prompter_test:guess_1_test/0
    **error:undef
```

I want to mock (stub?) the gets function in my test so that gets will return "aaaa" and then when I assert on get_guess() it should equal ["a", "a", "a", "a"].

How do I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two problems:

- The `prompter` module has two exported functions, but you only mock one of them (`gets`) with `meck:expect`. By default, Meck creates a new module that *only* contains the functions that you explicitly mock. You can change that by using the `passthrough` option:

  ```
  meck:new(prompter, [passthrough]),
  ```
- When you mock the `gets` function, all *module-prefixed* calls (i.e. `prompter:gets()`) are intercepted, but Meck has no way (yet?) of intercepting *internal* calls (e.g. the `gets()` call in the `guess` function), so you would still get the unmocked version of the function. There is no completely satisfactory way to avoid this. You could change the call in `guess` to `prompter:gets()`, or you could move `gets` into a separate module and mock that.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I tried to do add the module name to the function in the call ("change the call in guess to prompter:gets()").  That didn't work unfortunately.  So, I ended up pulling out gets() to its own separate module that I could then mock per the instructions from kjw0188.

Answer (score 7):

The first line says to create a new mocked module, `my_library_module`:

```
    meck:new(my_library_module),
```

Next, we mock the function `fib` in `my_library_module` to return 21 when 8 is passed in:

```
    meck:expect(my_library_module, fib, fun(8) -> 21 end),
```

We have some eunit assertions to test our mocked function.  The `code_under_test:run` call is what you want to replace with the the function using your mocked module, and the `21` is the result you are expecting from the function call:

```
    ?assertEqual(21, code_under_test:run(fib, 8)), % Uses my_library_module
    ?assert(meck:validate(my_library_module)),
```

Then we unload the mocked module:

```
    meck:unload(my_library_module).
```

If you wanted to write the same test for your module, you could write:

```
my_test() ->
    meck:new(console_io),
    meck:expect(console_io, gets, fun() -> "aaaa" end),
    ?assertEqual(["a", "a", "a", "a"], console_io:get_guess()), % Uses console_io
    ?assert(meck:validate(console_io)),
    meck:unload(console_io).
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I totally get it now.  However, the test still is not passing.  I updated the question above with my new code/test and the error I'm getting.  Hoping you can help me out.

Comment: What does meck:validate/1 actually do in the above examples? I can't work it out

Comment: There's another answer that might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43279705/whats-the-point-of-meckvalidate